How to fix Inconsistency detected by ld.so when using sprof to profile a .so library?
I'm trying to profile a shared library with sprof following this guide but when i run this cmd to generate the profile info:
sprof -p libdemo.so.1 $LD_PROFILE_OUTPUT/libdemo.so.1.profile

I get the error:

Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 929: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_update (args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
I've tried different ways to fix it but so far nothing works. Also tried this guide but got the same error. I want to get the profile data for the .so library.

Apropos, and perhaps even a dupe: What is causing sprof to complain about "inconsistency detected by ld.so"?

I saw that post but nothing there worked for me
